# System.FormatException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

This code keeps bringing up a:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean.

```
    public void BindToData()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
            string strproc = "TestReport";
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = StatusId.SelectedValue;
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = orgUnitId.SelectedValue;
                sda.Fill(ds);

                XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
                report.DataSource = ds;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }    
    }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestReport]
(           
    @Status bit,
    @OrgJed int
) 
AS  
BEGIN    
    SELECT TOP 1 OrgUnitID
    FROM    tblZaposleni_AD 
    WHERE  Status =    @Status AND 
        OrgUnitID = @OrgJed  
END
```

I have looked everywhere and there have been suggestions to do converts, but I simply can't find what exactly I should have to convert in this code. 
The problem is here, and I try everything but doesn't work.

```
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = StatusId.SelectedValue;
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = orgUnitId.SelectedValue;
```

Note: `StatusId` is DropDownMenu which has 2 options, `"0"` or `"1"`.  `OrgJed` is DropDownMenu which has values from `"1"` to `"10"`

Comment: The SelectedValue are strings and you have to convert to a Bit and Int.

Comment: `sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = StatusId.SelectedValue.ToString();`
  
`sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = orgUnitId.SelectedValue.ToString();`

Something like this doesnt work for me

Comment: StatusId is `DropDownMenu` which has 2 option from `0` or `1`
OrgJed is `DropDownMenu` which has value from `1` to `10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the strings in your `DropDownList`s to a bool and an int respectively for use in your parameters e.g.

```
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = StatusId.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(orgUnitId.SelectedValue);
```

Note: For robust code you should really use `Int32.TryParse()` but I will leave that as an exercise for you.